# Why is there difference between static Thread.currentThread().getName() and getName()?

Tags: java, multithreading

I thought about a Thread object like some abstraction that carries name and static Thread.currentThread() like the way to access to that Thread object. Obviously, it's wrong assumption.

```
public class App {

    static class TestedThread extends Thread {
        public void run() {
            // System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()); // is ok
            System.out.println(this.getName());// Why is there difference?
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestedThread base = new TestedThread();
        // base.start();

        Thread derived = new Thread(base);
        derived.setName("derived");
        derived.start();
    }
}
```

Is it something like that?
[image]

Comment: `Thread derived = new Thread(base);` Just don't do that.

Comment: @tkausl, ok! But I got this problem from an educational example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Thread.currentThread().getName()` and `this.getName()` return different names when you start the `derived` thread because `this` is not the same as `Thread.currentThread()`.

You create `derived` by using [the constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.lang.Runnable)) that takes in a `Runnable`. This creates a new thread that runs the `Runnable` (calls the `run` method). The argument you passed, `base`, is a `Thread` object, which also happens to be `Runnable`.

However, the fact that `base` is a `Thread` (and not some other `Runnable` things) is not relevant. `derived.start()` still only starts the `derived` thread by calling `base.run()`. It does not start the `base` thread.

So `Thread.currentThread()` is the `derived` thread, but `this` refers to the `base` thread.

Comment: Could you please take a relook? Did I correctly understand?

Comment: @Squared Not sure what all those arrows and colors mean, but yeah, you seem to have created a similar structure with your own classes, so I think you understood correctly. You can post another question if you are still confused.

Comment: Sorry for confusing! I mean the problem is that when we call derived.start() we then call run() which calls base.getName() , but not the derived.getName().

Comment: @Squared Yes that's right.

Answer (score 2):

It is a source of confusion that Thread implements Runnable. A Thread object is a Java Object that, once it starts, has a connection to an os thread. Having Runnable as an interface means we can separate a logical task, the Runnable, from the thing that runs it, the Thread. But letting Thread implement Runnable means the type system doesn't complain if you pass in a Thread as a constructor argument to another Thread.

When you pass in some thread A as a constructor argument to another thread B you are saying, A is some object with a run method that I want B to execute. When your code in A calls getName, that is getName on A, but the thread executing the code is B.

Passing A into B doesn't mean B will use A's os thread, it only means B will execute A's run method. `Thread.currentThread()` gets the Thread object that wraps the os thread executing the code.

Answer (score 0):

When `base` is running - by calling `base.start();` -  getName() inside run() will correctly return the name of base, which will be something like "Thread-0" by default.

When derived is running - by calling `derived.start();` -  it also executes base's run() method. Here, getName() will return the name of base (not derived) because getName() refers to the TestedThread object (base) on which it was called. This is true even though derived is the thread that is currently running the run() method.

It may be easier to understand if you add more logging to your example:

```
static class TestedThread extends Thread {
    public void run() {
        // Here this (running base or derived) always refers to the same instance - the base instance.
        // The reason is that you created derived with base as a parameter,
        // and the run from base always refers to base variable instance.
        // Thread.currentThread() on the other hand refers to the instance of Thread instance on which you called start.
        System.out.println("1: thid:" + Thread.currentThread().getId() + ", th ref:" + Thread.currentThread().hashCode() + ", this=" + this.hashCode() + ", " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        System.out.println("2: thid:" + Thread.currentThread().getId() + ", th ref:" + Thread.currentThread().hashCode() + ", this=" + this.hashCode() + ", " + getName());
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    TestedThread base = new TestedThread();
    // Here base.getName() returns "Thread-0"

    Thread derived = new Thread(base);
    // Here derived.getName() returns "Thread-1"
    // derived will execute code from base.run() - but code inside run() will refer to the base instance

    derived.setName("derived");
    // Here derived name is changed to "derived"

    base.start();
    derived.start();
}
```

On my computer it prints:

```
1: thid:15, th ref:1801046120, this=1990684586, derived
1: thid:14, th ref:1990684586, this=1990684586, Thread-0
2: thid:15, th ref:1801046120, this=1990684586, Thread-0
2: thid:14, th ref:1990684586, this=1990684586, Thread-0
```

as you see, the `this` always returns the same value, this is why getName() (which is actually this.getName()) returns the same value.